# 'snap to' pixel after applying transformations

Tags: processing

```
//given these coordinates for a rectangle (which I will draw with rectmode CORNER)
float layerX = -50;
float layerY = -50;
float layerW = 100;
float layerH = 100;

//and these transformations
translate( 300, 0 );
scale( 12, 1.5 );
scale( .5, .5 );

//which project those coordinates here.
float sx = screenX( layerX, layerY );
float sy = screenY( layerX, layerY );
float sw = screenX( layerX+layerW, layerY+layerH );
float sh = screenY( layerX+layerW, layerY+layerH );

//(this spits out 0, -37.5, 600, 37.5)
println( sx, sy, sw, sh );

//how do I modify the transformation to 'snap' 
//the transformed values to [0, -38, 600, 38], 
//effectively snapping to the pixel (and widening the rectangle)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to round the values to integers (whole numbers).

Simplest would be:

```
int sx = (int)screenX( layerX, layerY );
int sy = (int)screenY( layerX, layerY );
int sw = (int)screenX( layerX+layerW, layerY+layerH );
int sh = (int)screenY( layerX+layerW, layerY+layerH );
```

but using [round()](https://processing.org/reference/round_.html) will give you more accurate results, since casting to `int` will essentially [floor()](https://processing.org/reference/floor_.html) the value:

```
int sx = (int)round(screenX( layerX, layerY ));
int sy = (int)round(screenY( layerX, layerY ));
int sw = (int)round(screenX( layerX+layerW, layerY+layerH ));
int sh = (int)round(screenY( layerX+layerW, layerY+layerH ));
```